# Add params to array request

Tags: php, arrays

I have a pretty large array that I would need to parse, but the request changes depending on enabled/disabled parameters.

For example:

```
$array['a'][1]['b'][1]['c'][1] = 'asd';
$str = $array['a'][1];

dd($str);
```

This would give me:

```
Array
(
    [b] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
            (
                [1] => asd
            )

        )

    )

)
```

Which, of course, is correct. But now, if I know, that I need also the next parameter, I would need to add that like `$str = $array['a'][1]['b'];`.

But since there are way too many combinations, I wondered, if I can construct the call manually, something like this":

```
$str = $array['a'][1];
if ($b) {
    $str .= ['b'][1];
}
if ($c) {
    $str .= ['c'][1];
}

dd($str);
```

Any hints will be appreciated.

PS: I know I can do this with `eval`, but was really looking for a better solution:

```
eval("\$str = \$array$str;");
dd($str);
```

Comment: do you want get item of array by string containing key sequence '[a][1]...' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with Reference

```
$string = "['a'][1]['b'][1]";
// Maybe, not optimal, but it's not the point of the code
preg_match_all('/\[\'?([^\]\']+)\'?\]/', $string, $steps);

// "Root" of the array
$p = &$array;

foreach($steps[1] as $s) {
     // Next step with current key  
     if (isset($p[$s]) && is_array($p)) $p = &$p[$s];
     else throw new Exception("No such item");
} 
// Target value
$str = $p;
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/902275)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!